# Nutch .Net implementation

Tags: .net, nutch

We are building an enterprise search application and we use Lucene.net for indexing. We are looking to have a crawler.Is there a .Net implementation of Nutch - Web crawler? or is there any ongoing efforts for the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an effort for nutch.net for a while but it was abandoned.

Answer (score 2):

I don't experince with it, but you can give it a try - http://arachnode.net/
as it indicates, its data is stored in Lucene.Net indexes.